# While trying to use css for division within python code getting KeyError: '\n\t\t\tdisplay'

Tags: python, html, css

I have a problem writing via python code for the html and css content to report "Test_Report". While trying to use CSS for division tag within Python code, I'm getting KeyError: '\n\t\t\tdisplay'.
I think there might be some issue with .division. Please let me know how to go about resolving the error.

```
html='''<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Division Report</title>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: stretch;
                gap: 20px;
                margin: 20px;
            }
    
            .division {
                flex: 1 1 300px;
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
    
            h2 {
                margin-top: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="division">
                
                <p><strong>this is division1:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>This is list1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="division">
                
                <p><strong>this is division2:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>this is list2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="division">
                
                <p><strong>Key Challenges:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Legacy environment not available</li>
                    <li>ISD Azure environment not available</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="editorDemoTable" style="height: 413px;" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
    <td style="height: 18px; width: 203.325px;">Total</td>
    <td style="height: 18px; width: 267.975px;">{}</td>
    <td style="height: 18px; width: 50.6875px;">%completed</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 29px;">
    <td style="height: 29px; width: 203.325px;">Total completed</td>
    <td style="height: 29px; width: 267.975px;">{}</td>
    <td style="height: 29px; width: 50.6875px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="height: 22px; width: 203.325px;">Total new</td>
    <td style="height: 22px; width: 267.975px;"><span style="color: green; font-size: 13px;">{}</span></td>
    <td style="height: 22px; width: 50.6875px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="height: 22px; width: 203.325px;">Not completed</td>
    <td style="height: 22px; width: 267.975px;"><span id="demoId">{}</span></td>
    <td style="height: 22px; width: 50.6875px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="height: 21px; width: 203.325px;">some backlog</td>
    <td style="height: 21px; width: 267.975px;">{}</td>
    <td style="height: 21px; width: 50.6875px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>'''.format(100,200,300,400,500)
    
    with open(r"C:\Users\Test_Report.HTML", "w") as file:
            file.write(html)
```

Comment: If you use something like `.container {` the `{` starts a new placeholder. If you want to use `format` you have to to double the `{` and `}` characters that should not be placeholders. So `.container {` should be `.container {{` and closed with `}}`. The same applies to some other parts of the text.